# How to display search suggestions from an array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to display up to 10 options from a suggestions array and then give the user the ability to select the option, with that option now becoming the search query?

Html and AngularJS:

```
<ul class="suggestions" ng-show="showAutocomplete">
  <li ng-repeat="suggestion in autocomplete.suggestions" ng-show="suggestion.options.length > 0" ng-mousedown="searchForSuggestion()"><small>Searching &mdash;</small>
    {{suggestion.options[0].text}}//how to display up to 10 options
  </li>
</ul>
```

Suggestions array

```
$scope.autocomplete = {
    suggestions: []
};
$scope.showAutocomplete = false;
```

JS:

```
$scope.searchForSuggestion = function() {
    $scope.searchTerms = $scope.autocomplete.suggestions[0].options[0].text;
    $scope.search();
    $scope.showAutocomplete = false;
};
```

More JS:

```
var getSuggestions = function(query) {
  searchService.getSuggestions(query).then(function(es_return) {
    var suggestions = es_return.suggest.phraseSuggestion;

    if (suggestions.length > 0) {
      $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = suggestions;
    }
    else {
      $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = [];
    }

    if (suggestions.length > 0) {
      $scope.showAutocomplete = true;
    }
    else {
      $scope.showAutocomplete = false;
    }
  });
};
```

Suggestions is an array mapped to the $scope.autocomplete object.
I'm using PhraseSuggestion from ES and options is an array within the PhraseSuggestion object. Text is the actual option from the options array within the PhraseSuggestion object.

I hope that makes it a bit clearer - I'm a bit new to AngularJS and still learning it.

**UPDATE:**
I should be able to include the functionality that I'm seeking in the getSuggestions function, right? Just adjusting the if statements a bit... then all it really comes down to is the display, how to display up to 10 suggestions in the options array

Comment: what is the difference between suggestions and options? I understand you have options within your suggestions? Can you make an example?

Comment: You can nest another `ng-repeat` using `limitTo:10`? and define an `ng-click` for each?

Comment: @lex82 give me a minute to add more info to the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking to use a nested `ng-repeat` with a `limitTo` filter placed on it.

I've put together a plunker showing how you can use `limitTo` with an `ng-click` on your populated options here [http://plnkr.co/edit/8Mh...](http://plnkr.co/edit/8MhPoCTXI9eijP5Whl4s?p=preview).

If selecting an option alters suggestions, that should be fine and update the view accordingly.

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Im going to try this out and will let you know

Comment: Cool. It's of course not exactly the same as your code but you should be able to adapt it into what you're looking to do :D

Comment: still working on it, while working on it thought of an idea - will add to the question - too much for comment